# macOS Keyboard Shortcuts in Swift

Tags: macos, function, swift, keyboard-shortcuts, osx-yosemite

I am creating a macOS app and would like to create a keyboard shortcut for when the user taps the space bar for one of my buttons.

I am not sure where I should start and even where the documentation is for this? What should I be looking for?

Comment: Swift is a very new language. You are throwing away 15 years of Objective-C documentation if you search for a Swift solution from the beginning. Here's a guide in Objective-C: https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/EventOverview/HandlingKeyEvents/HandlingKeyEvents.html

Answer (score 3):

You can now add keyboard shortcuts for many of your UI elements directly in a storyboard, by clicking on the Attribute inspector and scrolling down to "Key Equivalent".  You just click in the Key Equivalent text field and press the key equivalent on your keyboard.